# Chrome version of Firefox plugin jsView

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, firefox-addon, dependencies

*Question:*
- what do you use to view dependencies and their corresponding file sizes in chrome.

*Background info:*
Now I have switched to Chrome as my primary dev browser i'd like to find a similar extention to Firefox's 'jsView' addon.
JsView has been around for years and is a super handy dev tool for viewing JS and CSS dependencies. It also conveniently displays the file sizes. 
I'd prefer to avoid having to dig deep into resources tab. Even then —and as far as I know— Chrome doesn't show the file size.

Comment: Solution: Switch back to Firefox.

Comment: From what you say JsView does, this is also done by web tools of Firefox too, Firebug does as well. So probably Chrome's dev tools does the same.

Answer (score 4):

JSView for Chrome:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsview/gbbhhhbdjckoiclnpaodmiehfmpeiefd?hl=en

Alternative plugin for Firefox 32 (since JSView doesn't work anymore).

Phoenix:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/phoenix/

Note, that by default Phoenix tries to open all JS/CSS files in its' own editor. Disable that feature (make them open in a new tab), because otherwise Phoenix crashes (or may crash) your browser.